# using javascript with buttons to change the colour of text (list)

Tags: javascript, html, css

what i want to do is have three buttons that all have the same list of text but when each button is clicked then only certain number of lines of text in the list are coloured while the rest is at the default colour set.

for example..

button one 5/10 coloured
button two 7/10 coloured
button three 10/10 coloured

basically something like this

https://www.hubspot.com/pricing/marketing

thanks

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow, please check this page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself? This isn't a code-writing or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough example of what I believe you are asking for.

```
<html>
<style>
    .selected {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btn1').click(function() {
        setSelected(1, 3);
      });
      $('#btn2').click(function() {
        setSelected(1, 6);
      });
      $('#btn3').click(function() {
        setSelected(1, 9);
      });
    });

    function setSelected(lower, upper) {
        for(var i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
            $('#itm' + i).addClass('selected');
        }
        for(var i = upper+1; i <= 9; i++) { 
            $('#itm' + i).removeClass('selected');
        }
    }
</script>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Button 1"/>
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="Button 2"/>
<input id="btn3" type="button" value="Button 3"/>
<ol>
    <li id="itm1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="itm2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="itm3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="itm4">Item 4</li>
    <li id="itm5">Item 5</li>
    <li id="itm6">Item 6</li>
    <li id="itm7">Item 7</li>
    <li id="itm8">Item 8</li>
    <li id="itm9">Item 9</li>
</ol>
</html>
```

Comment: @TonyP : please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers